# Rails GeoCoder, looping through existing database and geocode_by :address, :city, :state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation

I have imported a .csv file of 10,000 locations and I need to loop through the database and geocode_by a few fields rather than the usual "geocode_by :address"

I am using the geocoder gem.

My database scheme looks like this

```
    create_table "locations", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "Address"
      t.string   "City"
      t.string   "State"
      t.string   "Zip"
      t.float    "latitude"
      t.float    "longitude"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
    end
```

Can I do this in a controller action rather than on validation?
Should I do something like this:

```
 def index
    @locations = Location.all
    @locations.each do |l|
        new_address = "#{l.Address} #{l.City} #{l.State}"
        geocode_by = :new_address
    end
 end
```

But yea, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get things working with this controller code:

```
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 20, :order => :distance)
    else
      @locations = Location.all
      @locations.each do |l|
        if l.latitude.nil?
          new_location = "#{l.HP_Address_1} #{l.HP_City} #{l.HP_State}"
          s = Geocoder.search(new_location)
          l.latitude = s[0].latitude
          l.longitude = s[0].longitude
          l.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

It loops through every entry in the database, and if the latitude and longitude values have not been encoded it calls the correct geocoder function, and stores the returned lat / long values in the database.

I have 9k entries in my database, so I can only encode 2k per day due to the limit on the google maps api. But for folks used to encoding entries during creating using `geocoded_by` in their models, this will work in controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing I'd do with workers (delayed job or resque), since it might take some time to complete. But I'm not sure I understood the question, so this might not be the kind of answer you're expecting.

Comment: How would you go about implementing that using Resque for instance?

Answer (score 1):

There is a rake task for this if you want to do every record in a class.

rake geocode:all CLASS=YourModel sleep=0.25